# Remove state style after certain delay in Angular

Tags: angular-animations, angular13

I'm building Angular 13 application where redis database is pushing its changes, and I want certain numeric values to be animated (styled) depending on whether the value is increasing or decreasing. And after certain delay (let's say 3secons) I would like state style to be removed.

What I have until now is:

```
animations: [
 trigger('change', [
   state('increase', style({ backgroundColor: 'rgb(3, 190, 3)' })),
   state('decrease', style({ backgroundColor: 'red' })),
   state('',style({})),
   transition('* => *',animate(10)),
])
```

]

HTML part where I use the trigger, is default one:

```
<div [@change]="getState()" class="col-4 p-0">{{tennisWorkerObject.konecenTip.home | number:"1.2-2"}}</div>
```

getState() function have background logic to return either of the 3 states stated in animation definition above. But, its executed just once, after redis change notification.

And it's working properly, but after everything I've tried, I can't remove state style after above-mentioned 3 seconds.